# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/home/tsc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so"

Tags: pi-4, python-3, tkinter, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

I'm trying to run a simple script to verify the installation of customtkinter on my raspberry pi 4b.

```
import customtkinter

def button_callback():
    print("button clicked")

app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("400x150")

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="my button", command=button_callback)
button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

app.mainloop()
```

I've installed customtkinter and all the related code required, but I may be missing something.  I've ran this code on both bullseye and bookworm and get the same error message.

```
tsc@tsc:~/Desktop/Feeder $ python3 test6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsc/Desktop/Feeder/test6.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
  File "/home/tsc/Desktop/Feeder/customtkinter/windows/ctk_tk.py", line 41, in __init__
    TK_CLASS.__init__(self, **pop_from_dict_by_set(kwargs, self._valid_tk_constructor_arguments))
  File "/home/tsc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/tk.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.TkDnDVersion = _init_tkdnd(self)
  File "/home/tsc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/tk.py", line 28, in _init_tkdnd
    TkDnDVersion = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'tkdnd')
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/home/tsc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so": /home/tsc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux/libtkdnd2.9.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I go to the directory and list it, the "missing file" is there.

```
tsc@tsc:~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkinterDnD/linux $ ls -lart
total 160
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc   265 Oct 18 14:01 pkgIndex.tcl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tsc tsc 55135 Oct 18 14:01 libtkdnd2.9.2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc 16121 Oct 18 14:01 tkdnd.tcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc 21065 Oct 18 14:01 tkdnd_generic.tcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc  6231 Oct 18 14:01 tkdnd_compat.tcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc 10148 Oct 18 14:01 tkdnd_utils.tcl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tsc tsc 31443 Oct 18 14:01 tkdnd_unix.tcl
drwxr-xr-x 2 tsc tsc  4096 Oct 18 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 tsc tsc  4096 Oct 18 14:01 ..
```

Reinstalled the OS and the python code a number of times but I can't fix it.

What am I missing?

Tried with both the latest bullseye 64 bit update and the latest bookworm 64 bit update.

Code runs fine on my mac.